# Android: load file between two activities

Tags: android, file, load, record, sd-card

I did an Android app of two activities. In the first activity I record a sound and I save this on sdcard with this code:

```
private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        String fileaudio= new String("record");
        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileaudio + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
    }
```

In the second activity I must call back this File and I used this code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"Audio/fileaudio.wav");
```

but I get always "FileNotFound" error, but I noted that this file is present in Audio folder
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

pass the file path as an extra to the new activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, KNColorPickerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("FILE_PATH",
                        file.getAbsolutePath());
                startActivity(i);
```

then in your second avtivity, in `onCreate`

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        if(i.hasExtra("FILE_PATH")){
            String filePath = i.getStringExtra("FILE_PATH");
        }
```

Comment: shouldn't File file = new File(sdcard,"Audio/fileaudio.wav"); be File file = new File(sdcard,"Audio/record.wav");